# div in viewport with constraint

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, scroll

I am using jQuery to move a div vertically so that it always remains in the viewport. I have two problems with the solution so far. Firstly it keeps on moving down vertically, forever! I think I can constrain the div inside its parent div but for the life of me cannot get it to work. Secondly, the starting position is not at the top of the page and therefore when I start scrolling I have the equivalent gap above the div that was there before the scrolling started, where as ideally I would like the div to remain flush with the top of the window once the scrolling has begun. My code so far looks like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv");

        $(window).scroll(function(){            
            $scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, "slow" );          
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am new to jQuery so am struggling abit with how to achieve either of the things I am after. If anyone is able to point me in the right direction I would be very greatful, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to use `$` in a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the margin top would keep changing it in relation to its original position. That's why it keeps going down.

Try this

```
#scrollDiv {position: absolute; top: 200px;}  // change the top accordingly

$scrollDiv = $('#scrollDiv');
$window = $(window);

$(window).scroll(function() {
         $scrollDiv.css('top', $window.scrollTop() + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It kind of breaks the whole layout though having the div absolutely positioned. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: The code above is assuming that scrollDiv doesn't have any parents, which probably isn't the case here.

Try setting the scrollDiv's top to $window.scrollTop() - $scrollDiv.position().top